# PHP - Service layer class instantiation causing infinite loop

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, slim

I have service layer classes which performs the business logic.

I have a class say `UserService` which performs user role related service like checking if user is admin, user has access to project, user has particular role or not, etc. And there is a another class say `ProjectService` which deals with project related things like getting project members, project details, etc.

```
UserService 
   $projectService;  //class variable

   hasProjectAccess(){
   {
     ...
     projectMember = projectService->getProjectMembers();
     ...
   }

   isUserAdmin(){
       return true|false; //just an example
   }

ProjectService 
   $userService;    //class variable
   getProjectMembers(){
   {
     ...
     perform some logic to create array of members
     ...
     if(userService.isUserAdmin())
        .. perform some other logic
     ...
   }
```

I am using Slim 3, where I use it's `Container` class to instantiate and inject all dependencies.

Now when I try to instantiate `UserService` class I have to instantiate the `ProjectService` class inside it (using setters method), which in turn has to instantiate UserService class .... and so on... which creates an infinite loop (cyclic dependency).

I am trying to achieve something like in Java/Spring, where you have different services which you need in your class and they wired into it using Spring so you do not have to worry about the cyclic dependency.

I am not much familiar with PHP except the basics.

Let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) which is used as dependency container in Slim3, isn't that strong as Spring in Java f.ex. it is only a simple container, which just has the basic functionallity.

So when just using the pimple functions you need to initialize your objects which have a cyclic dependency by yourself:

```
class A {
    private $b;
    public function __construct(B $b) { $this->b = $b; }
}
class B {
    private $a;
    public function setA(A $a) { $this->a = $a; }
}

$container = new \Slim\Container;
$b = new B;
$a = new A($b);
$b->setA($a);

$container['A'] = function($c) use ($a) {
    return $a;
};
$container['B'] = function($c) use ($b) {
    return $b;
};
$aFromContainer = $container['A'];
```

I've made some small changes to the slim container that it will be possible to automate this process  *(althrough this work, I dont know how well it does in larger projects)*.

```
class MyContainer extends \Slim\Container 
        implements \Interop\Container\ContainerInterface {
    private $resolveStack = [];
    private $resolveLater = [];

    /**
     * @see \Pimple\Container::offsetSet()
     *
     * Additionally define objects which will be later set with a method.
     */
    public function resolveLater(string $id, callable $value, array $later) {
        $this[$id] = $value;
        foreach($later as $item) {
            if(!isset($this->resolveLater[$item])) $this->resolveLater[$item] = [];
            $this->resolveLater[$item][] = $id;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see \Pimple\Container::offsetGet()
     *
     * Additionally set objects which were previously defined in #resolveLater.
     */
    public function offsetGet($id) {
        if(isset($this->resolveStack[$id])) { return $this->resolveStack[$id]; }
        $this->resolveStack[$id] = parent::offsetGet($id);
        if(isset($this->resolveLater[$id])) {
            foreach($this->resolveLater[$id] as $item) {
                $this[$item]->{'set' . $id}($this->resolveStack[$id]);
            }
        }
        return array_pop($this->resolveStack);
    }
}
```

Example for the above:

```
class A {
    public function setB(B $b) { $this->b = $b; }
    public function setC(C $c) { $this->c = $c; }
}
class B {
    public function setA(A $a) { $this->a = $a; }
    public function setC(C $c) { $this->c = $c; }
}
class C {
    public function setA(A $a) { $this->a = $a; }
    public function setB(B $b) { $this->b = $b; }
}
$container = new MyContainer;
$container->resolveLater('A', function($container) {
    return new A;
}, ['B', 'C']);
$container->resolveLater('B', function($container) {
    return new B;
}, ['A', 'C']);
$container->resolveLater('C', function($container) {
    return new C;
}, ['A','B']);
$a = $container['C'];
var_dump($a);
```

This would output something like this:

```
object(C)[20]
  public 'b' =>
    object(B)[22]
      public 'a' =>
        object(A)[21]
          public 'b' =>
            &object(B)[22]
          public 'c' =>
            &object(C)[20]
      public 'c' =>
        &object(C)[20]
  public 'a' =>
    object(A)[21]
      public 'b' =>
        object(B)[22]
          public 'a' =>
            &object(A)[21]
          public 'c' =>
            &object(C)[20]
      public 'c' =>
        &object(C)[20]
```